# how can specify which websocket endpoint I sent to from nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, ws

What I did here is creating a nodejs server, then whatever I receive a message I send it back to all the clients.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const port = 6969;
const server = http.createServer(express);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })



wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(data);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

after this I create two pages admin.html and client.html in each one a websocket endpoint
like this

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:6969');
```

How could I change my code to make it send the messages just to the admin page?

Comment: The simplest approach would be for the connection established for the admin page to send something which is effect says 'I am admin' and then add a value to the admin ws, ie, ``ws._admin = true``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank u  @user3094755  i did what u said and it works
i added  `ws.send("i am admin")`in the admin page
and change the code in the server like this

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    if (data=="i am admin")
      ws.isadmin=true;
    else ws.isadmin=false;
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client.isadmin=true && client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(data);}
    })
  })
})
```

i do not think that this is the best way to do it so
if anyone have an idea pls do not hestate to share it with me